# Arrays keys with a radio button

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to access my random array keys with a radio button on each of them
I want to place the radio button only on the array 
 of the `allQuestions[index].anwsers` keys and it has 3 indexes keys.

I'm couldn't make it and this my work so far.

```js
const allQuestions = [{
    question: "Which of them is from compton",
    anwsers: ["Nas", "Tupac", "Omarion", "Kendick"],
    correctAnswer: "Kendrick"
  },
  {
    question: "founder of HipHop",
    anwsers: ["Tupac", "Eazy E", "Kendick", "Bambata"],
    correctAnswer: "Bambata"
  },
  {
    question: "Who won BET Hip Hop Album 2018",
    anwsers: ["Kendrick", "Bruno", "Jay Z", "Drake"],
    correctAnswer: "Kendrick",
  },
  {
    question: "Best Female HipHop Art 2018",
    anwsers: ["Azelia", "Nicki", "Cardi_b", "Mama Rap"],
    correctAnswer: "Nicki"
  }
]

function render() {
  var index, unique;
  var print = '<ul>';
  for (i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * allQuestions.length);
  }

  var showQuiz = document.getElementById('showQuiz');
  var showAnswers = document.getElementById('showAnswers');

  showQuiz.style.color = 'red';
  showQuiz.innerHTML = allQuestions[index].question;
  showAnswers.innerHTML = allQuestions[index].anwsers;

  // I'm tryin to ue sthe unshift method here but it' not workin
  showAnswers.unshift('<input type="radio" value="allQuestions.anwsers[]');

}
```

```html
<div id="question" style="text-align: center"> Quiz</div>
<button type="button" onclick="render()">Next Quiz</button>
<div id="showQuiz"></div>
<div id="showAnswers"></div>
```

Comment: the questions is not clear.What is the expected output?

Comment: the document.getElementById only returns one element; if you want multiples than don't address them by `id`, but by `class`

Comment: i want to put a radio button on the  elements of allQuestions[answers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears we are trying to use the Array function `unshift()` on a DOM element. What i believe you are trying to do is create a list of radio buttons for each answer in your `allQuestions.answers[]`, this can be done with a for loop, or a map like so:

**Edit** to add `answersAsHtml` and `join(" ")` this improves readability and joins each array element with a space instead of the default comma.

```js
const allQuestions = [{
    question: "Which of them is from compton",
    anwsers: ["Nas", "Tupac", "Omarion", "Kendick"],
    correctAnswer: "Kendrick"
  },
  {
    question: "founder of HipHop",
    anwsers: ["Tupac", "Eazy E", "Kendick", "Bambata"],
    correctAnswer: "Bambata"
  },
  {
    question: "Who won BET Hip Hop Album 2018",
    anwsers: ["Kendrick", "Bruno", "Jay Z", "Drake"],
    correctAnswer: "Kendrick",
  },
  {
    question: "Best Female HipHop Art 2018",
    anwsers: ["Azelia", "Nicki", "Cardi_b", "Mama Rap"],
    correctAnswer: "Nicki"
  }
]

function render() {
  var index, unique;
  var print = '<ul>';
  for (i = 0; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * allQuestions.length);
  }

  var showQuiz = document.getElementById('showQuiz');
  var showAnswers = document.getElementById('showAnswers');
  var answersAsHtml = allQuestions[index].anwsers.map(ans => `<input type="radio" value="${ans}">${ans}</input>`).join(" ");

  showQuiz.style.color = 'red';
  showQuiz.innerHTML = allQuestions[index].question;
  showAnswers.innerHTML = answersAsHtml;

}
```

```html
<div id="question" style="text-align: center"> Quiz</div>
<button type="button" onclick="render()">Next Quiz</button>
<div id="showQuiz"></div>
<div id="showAnswers"></div>
```

Comment: also, if you're looking for it to only allow 1 to be checked, just make sure they have the same name attribute, such as my example below.

Comment: THanks  very much
can you pls let me understan this     value="${ans}">${ans}  .   I'm not really familiar with the ES6 an also  how i can i take of the commas fomr the radio button

Comment: also, one other thing to note, using the arrow function syntax (=>) will really only work in chrome, so just a heads up if you copied it down.

Comment: basically the ${ans} allows you to specify a variable if you've used `` to make your string. so instead of `"variable: " + variable`. it would just be `\`variable: ${variable}\``

Comment: OKay....:)
I understand now.
pls anyway, I can take off the commas(,)  from it
and also to stop the array from repeatin

Comment: I have updated my answer to join without commas. Also, as @LukeGaskell described the strings wrapped with "backticks" or the ` character are called template strings and allow you to use variables inline by using `${xyz}` syntax. Keep in mind, these are pretty new features and Luke's answer provides a good example of how to achieve the same thing using more common browser functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write into an html element, that's not an array. You are probably looking for something more like this.

```
showAnswers.innerHTML = allQuestions[index].anwsers.map(function (answer){
        return '<input type="radio" name="answers" value="' + answer + '"/>' + answer
})
```

Comment: Good answer! Looks like you beat me to the punch!